# EMAIL via SMS ( and not the other way around, which is quite common)

Tags: sms

I want to know is there any technology which allows you to set up an sms gateway, via which users can send emails?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) or [Tropo](http://www.tropo.com) - these provide SMS gateways which allow you to respond to incoming SMS in whatever way you like.